# How to retrieve elements from array - PHP

Tags: php

I am able to push  two values (24, 69)  into my array. However, when i try to retrieve the values by `imploding`, i get **Array Array**  What could i be doing wrong in my code below ? I am trying to retrieve these numbers when i echo

PS: This question may seem basic.

**Index.php**

```
 for ($row = 1; $row <= $highestRow; $row++) {
         $number = trim($objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0)->getCellByColumnAndRow("0",$row)->getValue());
    if (is_numeric($number)) {
                            $patient_data[] = array($number);                         
    }
    }
   if (($patient_data)) {

         echo (implode(" ",patient_data));
         exit;
    }
```

Comment: Why do you want to 'implode' ? just use like `echo $array[0];`

Comment: You are _not_ pushing simple numbers into your array, you are pushing _an array_ containing a number each time.

Comment: @executable, it returns Array

Comment: @04FS you are right about that and how do i get the values ?

Comment: You are currently getting `Array Array` from implode, because you have _created_ an array of arrays. If you don’t want that, then don’t create an array of arrays to begin with, put push the simple number values into your array instead.

Answer (score 0):

Replace the part of code with below.

```
if (($patient_data)) {
   echo (implode(" ",$patient_data));
   exit;
}
```

You missed `$` to `patient_data` variable in implode function.

Comment: That is only a typo but not the solution